# Using a common variable through factories in a single module

Tags: angularjs

I have a webservices module as below:

```
angular.module('resources.webservice', ['ngResource'])

 .factory('EmployeeResource', ['$resource', 
   function($resource) {
     return $resource("http://www.website.com/person.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }])

   .factory('MachinesResource', ['$resource', 
   function($resource) {
     return $resource("http://www.website.com/machines.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }]);
```

What I am trying to do is instead of typing our the entire url in each factory replace it with a common variable as below

```
(function() {
var baseUrl = "http://www.website.com/";

 angular.module('resources.webservice', ['ngResource'])

 .factory('EmployeeResource', ['$resource', 
   function($resource) {
     return $resource(baseUrl + "person.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }])

   .factory('MachinesResource', ['$resource', 
   function($resource) {
     return $resource(baseUrl + "machines.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }])

})();
```

However when I implement this I get the following error and the app does not load:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: EmployeeServiceProvider <- EmployeeService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=EmployeeServiceProvider%20%3C-%20EmployeeService
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:78:12
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3540:19
    at Object.getService [as get]
```

I do not get the above error if I am using the first method i.e using the entire URL in the factory. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a constant

```
(function() {

 angular.module('resources.webservice', ['ngResource'])

 // see here...
 .constant('baseUrl',"http://www.website.com/")

 // then inject like anything else
 .factory('EmployeeResource', ['$resource', 'baseUrl', 
   function($resource, baseUrl) {
     return $resource(baseUrl + "person.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }])

   .factory('MachinesResource', ['$resource', 'baseUrl', 
   function($resource, baseUrl) {
     return $resource(baseUrl + "machines.pl/:id" , {id: '@id'}, {} );
   }])

})();
```

As I understand module constants, they differ from `value` in that you can't override them via a call to `$provide`.

Documentation is on [angular.Module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jim.. but it seems like the error was elsewhere